# full build solr index with large amount of data

Tags: solr

I have a text file containing over 10 million records of web pages.
I want to build solr index with this file every day(because this file is updated daily).
Is there any effective solutions to full build solr index at once? Such as using map reduce model to accelerate building process.
I think using solr api to add document is a little bit slow.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear how much content is in those 10 million records, but it may actually be simple enough to index those in bulk. Just check your solrconfig.xml for your commit settings, you may, for example, have autoCommit configured with [low maxDocs settings](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_3/updatehandlers-in-solrconfig.html). In your case, you may want to disable autoCommit completely and just do it manually at the end.

However, if it is still a bit slow, before going to map-reduce, you could think about building a separate index and then [swapping it with the current index](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_3/coreadmin-api.html).

This way, you actually have the previous collection to roll-back to and/or to compare if needed. The new collection can even be built on a different machine and/or more close to the data.

Comment: I found a map-reduce based solution from [this book](https://www.packtpub.com/big-data-and-business-intelligence/scaling-big-data-hadoop-and-solr-second-edition). Like what you say, I can build indexs separately in map phrase and merge them together in reduce phrase.